# Interface of an Interface without bein a map of a map in firestore

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

So i have an Ionic application, and i have my interfaces like this

```
export interface Info {
age: number;
gender: boolean;
actLvlVal: number;
BMR: number;
TDEE: number;
weight: number;
height: number;
}

export interface UserProfile {
    id?: string;
    name: string;
    info?: {
        [key: string]: Info
    };
    challenger?: boolean;
    typeOfPlan?: string;
    id_Plan?: string;
    updatedAt?: any;
 }
```

The issue that i have, is when i add the document to Firestore, the document gets saved as

```
id: "5ZP8Zmm0qRMGcNtSiVR0"
info: { (map)
 Info: { (map)
  BMR: 1897.2
  TDEE: 2940.66
  actLvlVal: "1.55"
  age: 21
  gender: false
  height: 70
  weight: 170
  name "Javier Soto"
 }
}
updatedAt: March 24, 2019 at 6:19:27 PM UTC-5
```

So what i want is to store the data in the doc as only one map, that would be the first one and not like a map of a map.

This is my set function

```
.set({
    id: userId,
    name: profile.name,
    info: {
      'Info': {
        age: infoTemp.age,
        gender: infoTemp.gender,
        actLvlVal: infoTemp.actLvlVal,
        BMR: infoTemp.BMR,
        TDEE: infoTemp.TDEE,
        weight: infoTemp.weight,
        height: infoTemp.height
      }
    },
    updatedAt: timestamp
  });
```

Comment: what about changing the `info?: {
        [key: string]: Info
    };` to `info?: Info`

Comment: for some reason it didn't let me at the beginning, when i was adding the document to firestore, but i will try it now